# PhoneGap authentication pattern against Grails backend

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs, grails, cordova

I'm developing a backend service in Grails that should serve both a web application and a mobile application.

The frontend is being developed using AngularJS and the mobile app will use the same AngularJS codebase to go native with PhoneGap.

Now, I'm looking for a proper way to implement the authentication with the Grails backend that works both for the web app and mobile app.

Three ideas:

1) Store username and password in LocalStorage and authenticate the user on the backend at every request

2) Use cookie based authentication (it's tricky to enable cookies in PhoneGap, I should 
extract from the AJAX response and attach in the AJAX request)

3) Develop a custom protocol that generates a token for every session in the backend and stores that in LocalStorage. The session token will be sent in every request to the backend.

4) Sign every request using a private/public key mechanism (similar to Amazon AWS). Even in this case, the backend has to verify the correctness of the signature for every request (there is not a session concept).

I don't trust the LocalStorage so much but I have no other ideas and I can't find any example (an example with other backend and frontend technologies would help the same).

You can assume that the backend will run on HTTPS.

Comment: 4) Use OAuth2, I believe there're implementation for PhoneGap

Comment: Thanks Igor. I prefer not to use OAuth2 because the implementation of a OAuth2 provider is out of the project budget. Anyway, even with OAuth2, the key/token storage will rely on LocalStorage capability, won't it? What about my other 3 alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for the third one, with some additions:

1. The first time the device is connected, you authenticate the user in some way (user/password or whatever). Then you send a persistence token to the device which saves that to the LocalStorage.
2. For each following session, upon opening the client exchanges the persistence token for a short lived session token (how much short lived is up to you, depending on the context).

This is similar for what you provide but reduces risks of man-in-the-middle and replay attacks.

Hope this help!